# Snap group of vertices into one vertex individually

Tags: vertices, vertex-groups, snapping

Instead of snapping each vertex individually, is there a fast way to snap multiple vertices into 1?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't get it but do you want to merge them? Oh never mind someone answered it

Comment: not necesery, just want to snap individual vertices into one without pressing any key like snapping do

Answer (score 4):

This way doesn't merge. It involves pressing keys, but you do have to tell the application what you want, somehow.

- <kbd>Keyboard .</kbd> (period) set the pivot point to 'Active Element'
- Make your selection, ensuring your target vertex is active, for instance by selecting it, and Box/Circle selecting the rest.
- Hit <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Yes. With the vertices selected, press <kbd>M</kbd>, and select for example At last, so all will be merged into the last one that you selected. By the way, M > By Distance is also used to remove duplicate vertices.

Comment: thanks, its pretty helpful! And is there any faster solution without merging them? without pressing any keys, like snapping do